# Is it possible to run Oracle Apex without cookies?

Tags: oracle-apex

I have an oracle apex 19.2 app.

My app is supposed to be integrated on my clients web sites as iframe. This is something which works very badly since Safari doesn't accept third party cookies (cookies of my app are considered third pary cookies). Chrome will end accepting third party cookies as of next year as well. So my app keeps showing the error : your session has expired.

My app pages are public and don't require any authentication scheme.

I was wondering if it's possible to make apex app work without Cookies.

Thanks.
cheers,